# Partial first moments of stable distributions?

Tags: heavy-tailed, stable-distribution

Given a stable distribution with parameters $(\alpha, \beta), \alpha>1$ is it true that its all first partial moments (i.e. the integrals of the form $\int_a^b x f(x) dx$, where $a$ and $b$ could be $\pm \infty$) exist? Intuitively the answer is yes as the expectation exists but I just want to confirm this.

Thanks,
V.

Comment: Don't almost all stable distributions have bounded density functions?  If, then, by "partial moment" you mean the integral of a positive power of the value over some bounded interval, then *a fortiori* it exists--there's no way it can diverge.

Comment: By the partial moment I mean the integral over an interval, but not necessarily bounded, could be $[0, \infty]$ for instance.

Comment: Those are infinite for moments of power $2$ or greater and $1\lt\alpha\lt 2.$  Do you count "infinite" as "existing"?

Comment: No, I am only interested in the first partial moments, i.e. $\int_a^b x f(x) dx$

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_distribution) answers that.

Comment: Am I missing something? I can see it has a mean for $\alpha>1$ but to me it is not evident that partial first moment exists.

Comment: How could it fail to exist??  If any partial first moment did not exist, then the moment would not, either.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Took me a while to realize - this is not obvious tbh.